# kartik daterangepicker ограничить выбор дат в виджете

Tags: php, yii2, виджет, datepicker

Подскажите кто сталкивался, знает. Есть виджет от картика(daterangepicker), нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было выбрать любой день за последний месяц(последним днем месяца считается "сегодня"). При этом другие дни светились серым и нельзя было их выбирать. Там есть опции типа 'startAttribute', 'endAtrribute', 'startInputOptions' и 'endInputOptions', но не совсем понимаю когда что использовать и та ли вообще это опция, что мне нужно, а может так вообще нельзя сделать с коробки. Код виджета ниже. Всем заранее спасибо.

```
                <?php
                    echo DateRangePicker::widget([
                        'name' => 'date_range_3',
                        'value' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
                        'convertFormat' => true,
                        'useWithAddon' => true,
                        'disabled' => true,
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'singleDatePicker' => true,
                            'timePicker' => true,
                            'timePickerIncrement' => 30,
                            'locale' => ['format' => 'Y-m-d H:m:s']
                        ]
                    ]);
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из документации, такая опция не предусмотрена из коробки.
Единственное, что у меня получилось сделать:

`'startAttribute' => 'from_date',
 'endAttribute' => 'to_date',
 'startInputOptions' => ['value' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('-1 month'))],
 'endInputOptions' => ['value' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s')]`

Такая настройка выделит даты так, как Вы хотели, но не заблокирует остальные.

Советую попробовать https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker

В данном виджете можно сделать нужные вам настройки таким образом:

`'pluginOptions' => [`

```
    'startDate' => '-1m',
    'endDate' => '0d'
```

`]`